# Migrate Query Rules from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, query-rule, promoted-results

I have a SharePoint 2013 Search farm in which I have a bunch of query rules. I plan to copy all these query rules to SharePoint Online. Is there a PowerShell script that can help me export the rules from SharePoint 2013 and import it in SharePoint Online? I tried searching but with no luck.